# How can I build has single query in laravel

Tags: laravel

[image: Table Image]

```
$tadaydate = ddate('m/d/Y');

$value1 = value_table::where('value_1', $tadaydate)->get();

$value2 = value_table::where('value_2', $tadaydate)->get();

$value3 = value_table::where('value_3', $tadaydate)->get();

$value4 = value_table::where('value_4', $tadaydate)->get();

$value5 = value_table::where('value_5', $tadaydate)->get();
```

Is there any chance to check with single query?

Comment: Depends on what you want. Do you want all rows where the `value_x` column has `$tadaydate` or do you want all rows where any of the `value_x` columns contains `$tadaydate`?

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi please explaim it .

Comment: @Jerodev i want to check $tadaydate to every column value_x .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "->whereIn()" function I believe.

```
$value_array = ['value1',...,'value5'];
$value_table->whereIn($tadaydate, $value_array)->get;
```

Comment: Silly me! You are right. Should I remove the answer, or leave it for reference?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$tadaydate=ddate('m/d/Y');
$result = value_table::where('value_1',$tadaydate)
                      ->orWhere('value_2',$tadaydate)
                      ->orWhere('value_3',$tadaydate)
                      ->orWhere('value_4',$tadaydate)
                      ->orWhere('value_5',$tadaydate)
                      ->get();
```

**Updated Answer**

```
$user_list = value_table::where(function($query) use ($tadaydate){
        $query->where('value_1', =, $tadaydate);
        $query->where('value_2', =, $tadaydate);
        $query->where('value_3', =, $tadaydate);
        $query->where('value_4', =, $tadaydate);
        $query->where('value_5', =, $tadaydate);
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: i use this query but i can't get correctly 

$result = value_table::where('status',=,1)
                     ->orWhere('value_1',$tadaydate)
                      ->orWhere('value_2',$tadaydate)
                      ->orWhere('value_3',$tadaydate)
                      ->orWhere('value_4',$tadaydate)
                      ->orWhere('value_5',$tadaydate)
                      ->get();

Comment: @Balaji The code you mentioned has a syntax error. It should be `value_table::where('status', 1)` or if you want to pass an operator as second argument to `where` then put it inside quotes `' '` like this `value_table::where('status', '=', 1)`.

Comment: @Balaji Also check my updated answer and please let me know work or not

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd how can i check the status is this query

Comment: @Balaji Just add where('status', 1) in query

Comment: @Balaji And status field check in your `value_table`

Answer (score 0):

You can combine then:

```
$query = value_table::where('value_1',$tadaydate)
         ->orWhere('value_2',$tadaydate)
         ->orWhere('value_3',$tadaydate)
         ->orWhere('value_4',$tadaydate)
         ->orWhere('value_5',$tadaydate)
         ->get()
```

You should use `where` instead of `orWhere` to connect the wheres with an `AND` instead of an `OR`

To simplify it in a loop:

```
$columns = 7;
$query = value_table::query();
for ($i = 1;$i <= $columns;$i++) {
     $query = $query->orWhere('value_'.$i,$tadaydate);
} 
$values=$query->get();
```

However you will have much more success if you normalise your table:

```
 table 
 -----------
 id | more columns

 value_table
 ------------
 id | table_id (fK) | value
```

And two models `Table` and `ValueTable` . That way (assuming proper eloquent setup) you can just do:

```
 $tableRow = Table::whereHas("value", function ($q) use ($tadaydate) {
       return $q->where("value",$tadaydate);
 })->get();
```

Comment: $columns = 7;

$query = value_table::query();

for ($i = 1;$i <= $columns;$i++) {
     $query = $query->orWhere('value_'.$i,$tadaydate);
} 
$values=$query->get();

this query is working for me but i want to check 'status' of the field how can i check the status

Comment: @Balaji what do you mean by "status of the field"?

Comment: i want to check the 'status', query like

$query = value_table::where('status', 1)->where('value_1', $tadaydate)->get()

If there is any possible to add 'status' check in  where condition in your mention query

$columns = 7;
$query = value_table::query();
for ($i = 1;$i <= $columns;$i++) {
     $query = $query->orWhere('value_'.$i,$tadaydate);
} 
$values=$query->get();

Comment: @Balaji replace `$query = value_table::query();` with `$query = value_table::where("status",1);`

Comment: i want check two condition  $query = value_table::where('status', 1)->where('value_1', $tadaydate)->get()

Comment: i give the query like  $query = value_table::where("status",1)->query();
for ($i = 1;$i <= $columns;$i++) {
     $query = $query->orWhere('value_'.$i,$tadaydate);
} 
$values=$query->get();

but it give error

Comment: @Balaji You shouldn't have `->query()` at the end you need to **replace** that line with the other

Answer (score 0):

You can use `whereIn` for this. In `whereIn` you can pass your array like this:

```
 $values_list = [$val1,$val2,$val3];
 $data = YourModel::whereIn($tadaydate, $values_list)->get();
```

Comment: This query assumes the column name is `$tadaydate` (which is a date)